# Error trying to use the Ansible dynamic inventory plugin for Azure

Tags: azure, ansible

I'm trying to use the azure_rm plugin for Ansible to generate a dynamic inventory for VMs in Azure, but am getting a "batched request" error of 403 when I try to run the sanity-check command:

```
$ ansible all -m ping 
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /project/ansible/inventory.azure_rm.yml with
ansible_collections.azure.azcollection.plugins.inventory.azure_rm plugin: a batched request failed with status code 403, url
/subscriptions/<redacted>/resourceGroups/<redacted>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines
...
```

Here are the specifics of my macOS setup:

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.10.3
  config file = /project/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/Users/me/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/Cellar/ansible/2.10.3_1/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/Cellar/ansible/2.10.3_1/libexec/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.9.0 (default, Dec  6 2020, 18:02:34) [Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.27)]
```

This is the inventory.azure_rm.yml file:

```
plugin: azure_rm
include_vm_resource_groups:
- <redacted>
auth_source: auto

keyed_groups:
- prefix: tag
  key: tags
```

And I've also added this to the local ansible.cfg file:

```
inventory      = ./inventory.azure_rm.yml
```

I've also defined the particulars for authenticating to Azure as environment variables:

```
$ env | grep AZURE
AZURE_TENANT=<redacted>
AZURE_CLIENT_ID=<redacted>
AZURE_USE_PRIVATE_IP=yes
AZURE_SECRET=<redacted>
AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=<redacted>
```

These are the same "credentials" that I used with Terraform to create the VMs which I'm now trying to dynamically inventory, so they should be good.  So at a bit of a loss as to what is behind the 403 error.

I then added a -vvvv option to the command and got some additional info:

```
$ ansible all -m ping -vvvv
ansible 2.10.3
  config file = /Users/me/project/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/Users/me/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/Cellar/ansible/2.10.3_1/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/Cellar/ansible/2.10.3_1/libexec/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.9.0 (default, Dec  6 2020, 18:02:34) [Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.27)]
Using /Users/me/project/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
setting up inventory plugins
host_list declined parsing /Users/me/project/ansible/inventory.azure_rm.yml as it did not pass its verify_file() method
script declined parsing /Users/me/project/ansible/inventory.azure_rm.yml as it did not pass its verify_file() method
redirecting (type: inventory) ansible.builtin.azure_rm to azure.azcollection.azure_rm
Loading collection azure.azcollection from /Users/me/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/azure/azcollection
toml declined parsing /Users/me/project/ansible/inventory.azure_rm.yml as it did not pass its verify_file() method
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /Users/me/project/ansible/inventory.azure_rm.yml with
ansible_collections.azure.azcollection.plugins.inventory.azure_rm  plugin: a batched request failed with status code 403, url
/subscriptions/<redacted>/resourceGroups/<redacted>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/2.10.3_1/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible/inventory/manager.py", line 289, in parse_source
    plugin.parse(self._inventory, self._loader, source, cache=cache)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/2.10.3_1/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible/plugins/inventory/auto.py", line 59, in parse
    plugin.parse(inventory, loader, path, cache=cache)
  File "/Users/me/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/azure/azcollection/plugins/inventory/azure_rm.py", line 206, in parse
    self._get_hosts()
  File "/Users/me/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/azure/azcollection/plugins/inventory/azure_rm.py", line 263, in _get_hosts
    self._process_queue_batch()
  File "/Users/me/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/azure/azcollection/plugins/inventory/azure_rm.py", line 405, in _process_queue_batch
    raise AnsibleError("a batched request failed with status code {0}, url {1}".format(status_code, result.url))
```

Has anyone come across this before and figured out a fix?  I'm assuming the Service Principal I'm using is missing some role or permission, but I have no idea what it is given the same SP is used to provision the VM in the first place.

Comment: did you ever find a cause of this?

Comment: You have Azure permission issues [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42134892/the-client-with-object-id-does-not-have-authorization-to-perform-action-microso/52982916#52982916)

Answer (score 0):

Add the collection to get the latest version and then try this:

plugin: azure.azcollection.azure_rm

This will ensure you're using the latest and not the built-in version that won't contain bug fixes and support newer api versions.

Comment: At least explain it briefly. What is it? and how to use it? the benefit of using it,etc...