# Azure aks automated deployments won't work on multiple branches

Tags: github-actions, devops, azure-aks, cicd

I've been running automated deployments for multiple services in my k8s cluster in a dev env.

Now the services are ready for production and I wanted to duplicate the process. For some reason the deployment only want to work on one of the branches. Whether this is linked to app registrations or some other workflow service, I'm not sure since I don't have access to that subscription.

The workflow file is identical for the to env and variables are assigned like this:

```
CLUSTER_NAME: ${{ github.event.ref == 'refs/heads/main' && 'prod-aks' || 'dev-aks' }}
```

It fails on this step:

```
  - name: Get K8s context
    uses: azure/aks-set-context@v3
    with:
      admin: "false"
      cluster-name: ${{ env.CLUSTER_NAME }}
      resource-group: ${{ env.CLUSTER_RESOURCE_GROUP }}
      use-kubelogin: "true"
```

And gives the following error:

Message: The client '--' with object id '--' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/listClusterUserCredential/action'

Comment: I assume client '--' is <redacted> not double dash? If so - it seems like duplicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42134892/the-client-with-object-id-does-not-have-authorization-to-perform-action-microso

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The client with object id does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.DataFactory/datafactories/datapipelines/read' over scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42134892/the-client-with-object-id-does-not-have-authorization-to-perform-action-microso)

Comment: @ravenwing yes, client is redacted. I'll take a look at the link provided, thank you!

Comment: @ØysteinSeel Is this resolved with the help of above Docs?

Comment: @NaveenSharma I posted my solution bellow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current app registration only allowed a single branch from the github repository. Adding an additional federated credential, solved the issue